# Como customizar impressão no navegador

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Gostaria de customizar a impressão das páginas no `html` de forma que somente o número das páginas seja exibido.

Verifiquei que é possível remover o cabeçalho e o rodapé

```
@page 
{
    size:  auto;
    margin: 5mm;
}
```

mais não consegui deixar somente os números das páginas.

Existe alguma forma em `javascript` ou `jquery` para customizar essa necessidade.

Obrigado

Comment: Então vc removeu o cabeçalho e o rodapé o os números das páginas sumiram junto é isso?

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Comment: Cara se forem capítulos pequenos que caibam apenas um por página vc até consegue uma solução, mas se for um texto longo corrido onde vc não pode quebrar em sessões que caibam em uma página ai fica complicado. Se for apenas um conteúdo por página ai é possível usando CSS

Comment: Já tentou `@media print { ... }` ? É um uso de media queries que permite que o CSS seja aplicado somente para impressão, no media print, vc pode usar display:block; ou display:none para os elementos que vc quer que sejam impressos ou não.

Answer (score -1):

Seguinte meu amigo, uma vez eu precisei fazer isso tambem, é bem chatinho rsr mas deu certo.

talvez não seja a melhor maneira de fazer isso mas esse código te ajuda.

```css
*{
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
    }

    .conteudo_page{
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     width:100%;
     height:95%;
        padding-bottom: 5%;
      background-color: red;
    }

    .conteudo_page2{
     position:absolute;
     top:100%;
     left:0;
     width:100%;
     height:95%;
        padding-bottom: 5%;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .page_number{
     position:absolute;
     top:95%;
     left:0;
     width:100%;
     height:5%;
      background-color: blue;
      display: none;
    } 

    .page_number2{
     position:absolute;
     top:195%;
     left:0;
     width:100%;
     height:5%;
      background-color: blue;
      display: none;
    } 

    .number_page{
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    @media print{

        .page_number{
            display: block;
        }
        .page_number2{
            display: block;
        }

        .conteudo_page{
            padding-bottom: 0;
        }

        .conteudo_page2{
            padding-bottom: 0;
        }


    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="conteudo_page">
        <h1>pagina 1 aqui</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="page_number">
        <p class="number_page">Página 1</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="conteudo_page2">
        <h1>pagina 2 aqui</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="page_number2">
        <p class="number_page" style="">Página 2</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

tente criar um html com esse código para testar.

basicamente o que eu fiz foi criar uma `div` que voce vai colocar dentro o  que você quer na página 1.

```
<div class="conteudo_page">
    <h1>pagina 1 aqui</h1>
</div>
```

ela vai ocupar 100% da tela. porem em 5% dela tem uma div que irá aparecer  somente na impressão e com o numero da página, ali você pode colocar o que quiser como rodapé:

```
<div class="page_number">
    <p class="number_page">Página 1</p>
</div>
```

eu coloquei Página 1. e ai você segue o mesmo principio para as outras paginas que você quiser.

obs: tem que fazer as classes delas como fiz na parte do css:

e tambem mandalas aparecer e reduzir o padding na hora de imprimir:

```
.page_number{
        position:absolute;
        top:95%;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:5%;
      background-color: blue;
      display: none;
 } 

@media print{

    .page_number{
        display: block;
    }

    .conteudo_page{
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

espero ter ajudado

ahh lembrando que você precisa desativar o cabeçalho e rodapé do seu navegador

Comment: Amigo vc viu o que acontece com seu código quando vc coloca 1000 caracteres em cada "página"? Ele só conta as duas primeiras página, mesmo o documento tendo mais de 10 páginas...

Comment: @hugocsl nossa não tinha percebido isso não, acho que não vai se aplicar se as paginas forem muito grandes então. Existe como arrumar?

Comment: Até onde eu tinha testado mais cedo não há como. a não ser que ele separe o conteúdo em pequenos blocos como comentei la na pergunta dele. E a forma como vc fez ele tb teria que contar na mão quantas páginas tem o que tb não é adequado, tem que ter um contador automático pra isso

Comment: é infelizmente resolvi meu problema assim na época, lembro que tem um código que faz a div ir para outra pagina caso ela não caiba na pagina, vou postar esse codigo na resposta

Comment: Mesmo assim não vai adiantar pq o conteúdo vai empurrar o número para outra página, então se o conteúdo for do tamanho de duas página a primeira pagina fica sem número e o numero 1 só vai aparecer na outra página... mas pode tentar ai pra ver...

Comment: faz sentido, vou ver se tem uma forma de ignorar as divs de paginação